# Ruby on Rails Generalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to make an Generalization of some classes on my application.
I have an "Employee" class that has "number", "name" and "salary" as attributes.
I have the "Worker" class and the "Salesman" class that are both Employees and, therefore have all the "Employee" attributes.
For example, when creating a new "Worker", I have to put data on my "Employee" class and on my "Worker" class...
How do I make this generalization on RoR?

(http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/sql_designer/sql_images/fig13.gif)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Isn't `Employee` a generalization? Any code you put into this class will be inherited by `Worker` and by `Salesman`, so you don't need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all sure what you're asking, but I suspect the answer may be [single table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html).

Comment: Good guess! The 'database' tag should have clued me in.

Comment: That's what I was looking for!
Thank you guys very much!
Sorry for not being clear on my question...